# String written to child process corrupted?

Tags: c++, pipe, fork

I want to execute a program in a child process. The program works when I run it directly in the terminal: It waits for some input and Control+D/EOF has to be send before it processes it.

In my code below the program does not seem to receive a string properly, it seems as if it only sees some part or nothing at all when it receives EOF which also seems to happen several times even though I only send it once.

If anyone can tell me what is going wrong here?

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      int pipes[2][2]; //pipe[0] read, pipe[1] write

      #define PARENT_READ_FD  ( pipes[1][0] )
      #define PARENT_WRITE_FD ( pipes[0][1] )

      #define CHILD_READ_FD   ( pipes[0][0]  )
      #define CHILD_WRITE_FD  ( pipes[1][1]  )

      // pipes for parent to write and read
      assert( (pipe(pipes[1])) == 0 );
      assert( (pipe(pipes[0])) == 0 );

      int pid = fork();
      if(pid == 0) {
          char *argv[]={"/workspace/osm/overpass/osm3s_v0.7.51/bin/osm3s_query", "--db-dir=$DB_DIR"};

          assert( (dup2(CHILD_READ_FD, STDIN_FILENO)) != -1);
          assert( (dup2(CHILD_WRITE_FD, STDOUT_FILENO)) != -1);

          close(CHILD_READ_FD);
          close(CHILD_WRITE_FD);
          close(PARENT_READ_FD);
          close(PARENT_WRITE_FD);

          execv(argv[0], argv);
      } else if(pid > 0) {
          char buffer[1000];
          int count;

          close(CHILD_READ_FD);
          close(CHILD_WRITE_FD);

          int query_size = strlen(query.c_str()) + 1;
          int succesful_write = write(PARENT_WRITE_FD, &query, query_size);
          assert(succesful_write==query_size);
          close(PARENT_WRITE_FD);

          // Read from child’s stdout
          while( count = read(PARENT_READ_FD, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1) > 0){
            cerr << buffer << endl;
          }
      } else {
        cerr << "Could not fork child process" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
```

The error output from the program is for example (it changes every time the program is run):

```
    line 1: parse error: Unknown type "�"
    line 1: parse error: An empty query is not allowed
    line 1: parse error: Unknown type "n"
    line 1: parse error: An empty query is not allowed
    line 1: parse error: Unknown type "�"
    ...
```

Comment: This is not a complete program.  Where is `pid` coming from? You are depending on the side effect of the code in the `assert`ion which is bad because you cannot rely on it being executed. `argv` must be terminated with a `nullptr`.  Also note that – unlike a shell – `execv` won't perform parameter expansion of its arguments so you'll pass the `$DB_DIR` literally to the child process.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy the top bit of the program; I edited it now. About assert: I will save the return values in variables and assert then, that solves that issue right? What does "argv must be terminated with a nullptr" mean please? Thanks for the hint about $DB_DIR, I'll fix that.

Comment: Does it mean adding just NULL as the last element in `argv`? Why is that necessary?

Comment: Yes, you must put `NULL` (or, better yet, `nullptr`) as the last element. It is necessary because otherwise, the `execv` function has no way to figure out where the array ends.  C and C++ offer no way to determine the length of an array once it has decayed to a pointer.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. I adjusted my code now to incorporate all of the above. Sadly it still does not work. If you have any other ideas, please let me know.